# Java Ternary Operator to set True or false

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I am trying to set a condition and set true or false as follows but it returns false all the time.

```
boolean checked = (categoriesCursor.getString(3) == "1") ? true
                    : false;

Log.i("Nomad",categoriesCursor.getString(3)+ " "+checked);
```

When i try to output the values i get the following.

```
01-12 00:05:38.072: I/Nomad(23625): 1 false
01-12 00:05:38.072: I/Nomad(23625): 1 false
01-12 00:05:38.072: I/Nomad(23625): 1 false
01-12 00:05:38.072: I/Nomad(23625): 1 false
01-12 00:05:38.072: I/Nomad(23625): 1 false
01-12 00:05:38.072: I/Nomad(23625): 0 false
01-12 00:05:38.072: I/Nomad(23625): 0 false
```

Comment: A comment on your code: Why are you using the ternary operator here?  You could just say `boolean checked = "1".equals(categoriesCursor.getString(3));`

Comment: A comment on all the answers here: `"1".equals(categoriesCursor.getString(3));` is better than `categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1")` because there's less opportunity for a NullPointerException.

Comment: @DanielKaplan wow. i didnt know u could do something like that :D

Comment: `str.equals("literal")` is better than `"literal".equals(str)` because errors relating to `str` containing `null` are caught, and it's more readable. (Also `? true : false` is pointless - just leave it out.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It returns `false` all the time because you are comparing *references*, not *strings*. You probably meant this instead:

```
boolean checked = (categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1")) ? true
                : false;
```

Which happens to be equivalent to this:

```
boolean checked = categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1");
```

And in case `categoriesCursor.getString(3)` may be `null`, you will be safer doing this instead:

```
boolean checked = "1".equals(categoriesCursor.getString(3));
```

Comment: what does the last statement do ?

Comment: @HarshaMV: It checks whether `"1"` is _equal_ to the _string_ you got from the cursor.

Comment: @HarshaMV: Java has string constants, and they behave as String objects; all methods available to the `String` class are also available to `String` constants.

Answer (score 3):

Use `equals` instead of `==`

```
boolean checked = (categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this

```
(categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1")) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1")` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to compare strings, you'll have to use the `equals` method:

```
categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1")
```

Secondly, you don't need the ternary operator here. `equals` already results in a boolean, so simply assign it:

```
boolean checked = categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
boolean checked = (categoriesCursor.getString(3).equals("1")) ? true : false;
```

Don't use `==` to compare String contents.

**NOTE**: The `==` operator can't be overloaded or modified in JAVA.  If you are using `object1 == object2`, where `object1` and `object2` are Strings or any other object, you'll checking whether the references point to the same underlying object.  This will not compare the contents.

Answer (score 1):

First there's no need for ternary operator. Then you must use `equals()`  instead of `==` . Because `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.